# Check Sign on Table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 100 cells in my table view, when I put check sign on selected cell using this

```
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

it's also visible on other cells automatically, I do not understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Table view cells are reused, you have to make sure that not only the check mark is set on particular cells but also the check mark is **not** set on the others.

For example

```
if (somethingHappens) {
   [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
   [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always clear cell before show, than check condition. Try this:

```
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

if (shouldCheckMark) {
   [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```